# Access specific extension object data from page code

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to build an addon that will observe and collect XHR and image responses received on a page and make them available to page script (on that page) for further inspection.

In my 'http-on-examine-response' observer code, I push URLs I'm interested in, into an array for their associated window, into an object, something like this -

`myWindowId = resp.outerWindowID+'-'+resp.currentInnerWindowID;
storedResponses[myWindowId].push(subject.URI.spec);`

(I thought that approach may be better than using tab references to identify unique source windows)

The relevant arrays are updated automatically as any page makes a request.

I'd like to be able to query the relevant array from page script or a bookmarklet at any time.

Should I set up port.on..., or postMessage() communication between the page/bookmarklet, content script and extension, or use a pageMod to write the appropriate array directly to an unsafeWindow global object on the relevant page?

I couldn't figure out how to make a pageMod write a specific array to a specific page as soon as the new responses were observed.

Full source is here -
https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1064905/latest/

I think it's all working, apart from getting the data back on to the page.

Comment: yes, sharing the code you have so far would help! You should be able to send any data you collect to a page via either worker.postMessage(data) or worker.port.emit('event', data). The tricky part is tracking the workers you create and correctly identifying the worker you want to send the data to.

Comment: Hi @canuckistani thanks for your help. I added a link to the Add-on Builder code.

Comment: Side-note: You should be using [weak maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) instead of dealing with window IDs directly. This approach will also make sure that your extension doesn't leak memory.

Comment: Thanks @Wladimir, I hadn't heard of WeakMaps. The leaking memory is a good point though, and I've tried to make sure everything gets cleaned up in the full code. I just use the window IDs to create a text key on the object, not the window objects themselves as keys. Is that where you thought a WeakMap may be better - for the `storedResponses` object in the question? Sorry if I've misunderstood...

Comment: @Nils: Yes, `storedResponses.put(window, data)` will just work (at least in Firefox 13 and above) and you don't have to worry about inner/outer windows or cleaning up.

Comment: @WladimirPalant: Thanks, that makes sense. Would using just the window references make it any easier to get the `data` (the response URI array) back to script on the window it came from? Can I just set the data in the window? Something like `window.globalVar=data;`?

Comment: @Nils: `XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap(window).globalVar=data` would normally do but I think that the SDK doesn't define `XPCNativeWrapper` in the module context.

Answer (score 0):

With help from Wladimir Palant, I found that `XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap()` is defined and does what I needed from the SDK module context. It allowed me to set variables directly in a window from my addon.

More info about wrappers here -
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCNativeWrapper